# How can i use regex to parse js class names along with the code wrapped inside it?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse class name and the contents wrapped inside a js class with regex. I am using **python** to do the parsing. Here is the example code which i am trying to parse. What i expect to get by matching with regex is the list of class names and all the contents inside the class ( all methods, variables )

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}

class Square {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

i wrote this pattern to match the above code

```
class\s(.*)\{(.*)\}
```

But it matches differently as seen in the picture

[image]

As far as i know the regex which is supposed to stop at first curly brace, stopped at the second class curly brace, what am i doing wrong, what is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you need this regex to work for any valid js (including minified), or just on on code formatted as in the example given?

Comment: just for the code formatted as in the example

Comment: Regular expressions are not a good tool for parsing a grammar like Javascript.

Comment: what is the correct way to do that @JonathonReinhart without regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: `class\s+(.+?)\{(.+?)\n\}` should do the trick

There are two issues with your attempted solution

1. You are using a greedy quantifier (`(.*)\{`) for the class name cature group, where a lazy quantifier is needed (`(.+?)\{`). This is causing the capture group to spill over until the final occurrence of `\{`.
2. You also need a lazy quantifier (`(.+?)\n\}`) to dictate when the capture group for the class body ends. This will only work for formatted code where a class clearly ends in `\n`, since all other instances of `}` will be preceded by indentation. I don't believe it's possible to create a regex that can separate a class body in the general case, unfortunately.

Edit: I also replaced your `*`s with `+`ses where I think it's appropriate in order to assert that some character must appear in the class name and in the class body

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Pypi regex library](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) that supports recursive regex, this will work for any number of sub-blocks:

```
import regex

strin = '''
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}

class Square {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
'''
res = regex.findall(r'(class\s+\w+\s+({(?:[^{}]+|(?2))*}))', strin)
print res[0][0]
print '----------------------------------------'
print res[1][0]
```

**Output:**

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
----------------------------------------
class Square {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/0H5JmU/1) (using PCRE because regex101 doesn't use `regex` module)